# vim word boundaries in syntax files

Tags: syntax-highlighting, regular-expression

I have a syntax file with the following definitions:

```
syn keyword pythonBuiltinFunc           __import__ abs all any
                                        \ bin bool bytearray
                                        \ callable chr classmethod compile complex
                                        \ delattr dict dir divmod
                                        \ enumerate eval
                                        \ filter float format frozenset
                                        \ getattr globals hasattr hash hex
                                        \ id input int isinstance issubclass iter
                                        \ len list locals
                                        \ map max min next
                                        \ object oct open ord pow property
                                        \ range repr reversed round
                                        \ set setattr slice sorted
                                        \ staticmethod str sum super
                                        \ tuple type vars zip
                                        \ nextgroup=pythonArgs skipwhite
```

The problem is that this matches occurrences of `next` (e.g.) even when that name is referenced as an object's attribute, as in `obj.next`, and this messes up the highlighting.

While I might buy that it's useful to not shadow built-in names, I'm not sure that I buy this for bound names.

Does any one have thoughts on how to apply the above definitions, but exclude the pathological case I mentioned below? I guess I'd be allowing whitespace in the word pattern, but ignoring it in the match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use syn match instead of syn keyword for this kind of things:

```
syn match pythonBuiltinFunc "\<next\>"
```

For syn keyword, from syntax.txt:

> It can only contain keyword characters, according to the 'iskeyword' option. It cannot contain other syntax items. It will only match with a complete word (there are no keyword characters before or after the match). The keyword "if" would match in "if(a=b)", but not in "ifdef x", because "(" is not a keyword character and "d" is.

Comment: This is indeed what I ended up doing. Thanks!